# extracting letters from LSD.test output in agricolae

Tags: r, anova, posthoc

I'm using `LSD.test` in `agricolae` packages

Below is a reproducible example

```
library('agricolae')
group <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
variable <- c(1,2,1.5,10,11,12,22,23,21)
df <- data.frame(cbind(group,variable))
model <- aov(variable~group,data=df)
LSD.test(model,"group",p.adj="bonferroni")
```

I'm getting the below output which is great

```
$statistics
  MSerror Df Mean       CV  t.value      MSD
  0.8035714  7 11.5 7.794969 3.127552 2.289134

$parameters
  test  p.ajusted name.t ntr alpha
  Fisher-LSD bonferroni  group   3  0.05

$means
variable std r        LCL       UCL Min Max   Q25  Q50   Q75
1      1.5 0.5 3  0.2761907  2.723809   1   2  1.25  1.5  1.75
2     11.0 1.0 3  9.7761907 12.223809  10  12 10.50 11.0 11.50
3     22.0 1.0 3 20.7761907 23.223809  21  23 21.50 22.0 22.50

$comparison
NULL

$groups
variable groups
3     22.0      a
2     11.0      b
1      1.5      c

attr(,"class")
[1] "group"
```

I wanted to extract the median and letter from this output.

To extract the median of group 3 for example, I used this function

```
output [[5]][[1]][[1]]
```

that gives this output

```
[1] 22
```

Till now, everything is fine. I'll explain the problem and ask the question below.

Now, I need to extract the letter as well.

I tried the following code

```
output [[5]][[2]][[1]]
[1] a
Levels: a b c
```

My question is:
Is there any way to get rid of the `Levels: a b c` statement in the code and get only the letter?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You could do `as.character(output [[5]][[2]][[1]])`, but keep in mind that the levels are present because you are looking at a factor variable.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen This's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for prompt reply and help. Thanks for clarifying the reason, I only needed it to create a final table for the results. If you posted it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: That is NOT the mean. Q50 is the _median_.

Comment: @42- Thanks for clarifying! I -of course- know that Q50 is the median but didn't know that it's the one reported in the output. Thanks again. I've edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
as.character(output [[5]][[2]][[1]])
```

Solved it, thanks to @Tim Biegeleisen's comment